# Findnext after function call

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office

When I call my function (you can see the Line, where I commented), it does not loop, because `.FindNext(Cell)` returns `nothing`. If I remove the line though. It loops the appropriate amount, but I can not get the string, I want to append. It seems to me like some kind of call by value problem. Anyone has an idea?

Here is my Code:

```
Sub NachInhaltSuchen()
Dim result As String
result = ""
For Each ws In ActiveCell.EntireRow
        With ws.Cells
            Set Cell = .Find(what:="x", LookAt:=xlValues)
 
            If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = Cell.Address
                Do
                    Dim shortName As String
                    shortName = Cells(1, Cell.Column)
                    Dim semName As String
                    semName = SeminarName(shortName) 'If you remove this Line, it loops the appropriate amount of times
                    result = result & shortName & ": " '& semName - this should be re-added once it works
                    Set Cell = .FindNext(Cell)
                    If Cell Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                Loop Until Cell.Address = FirstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
MsgBox result

End Sub

 

Public Function SeminarName(ByVal name As String) As String
    Dim longName As String
    longName = ""
    Dim row As Integer

    With Worksheets("Seminare")
        Set c = .Cells(1).EntireColumn.Find(what:=name)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            longName = .Cells(c.row, 2)
        End If
    End With
    SeminarName = longName
End Function
```

Comment: Your first procedure shouldn't work - `LookAt:=xlValues` should be `LookIn:=xlValues`.  You can `LookAt` either `xlWhole` or `xlPart`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest one `Find` within another and then use `FindNext` to repeat the first `Find`. Since your function is basically just a lookup, you could use `Vlookup` instead:

```
Public Function SeminarName(ByVal name As String) As String
    Dim longName As String
    longName = ""
    Dim match
    match = application.vlookup(name, Worksheets("Seminare").Range("A:B"), 2, false)
    If Not iserror(match) Then longName = match
    SeminarName = longName
End Function
```